# difficult angle problem with a square on the edge of a circle

Tags: circles, angle

[image]

I want to know how to calculate $\theta$, every other variable in the picture is known. The solution should still work if there are more than $2$ triangles in the square. $a$ is always the same and I want to be able to change $r$ however I want.

( I was able to do it for $a = r$, $\theta = {\omega \over 2}$ with $\omega = 180 - \gamma$. But I couldn't figure it out for the general case. Maybe $\alpha$ (orange) looks a little bit like $\gamma$ (purple) in the picture, they are of course not the same, sorry about that.

You can create a right triangle by splitting $d$ in half and connecting this point to the center of the circle, I don't know if that helps but I used that triangle to calculate $\gamma$ with $\cos$. Other formulas I used are $l = r\alpha$ for the length of a circle piece and $s = 2r\sin{\alpha \over 2}$ for the distance of $2$ points on the edge of the circle, also don't know if that helps at all. )

I want to program something and this is the last piece I need, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I suppose the center red line passes through one of the diagonal of the square. Then, you can use symmetry. Also, recall the inscribed angle theorem. You can express all the angles that appear here using $\alpha$ only. You don't need to use $\sin$ or $\cos$.

Comment: Also, please consider assigning letters such as A, B, C, D, O, etc. to those points in the picture. It will make communication much easier.

Comment: Oh I forgot about the inscribed angle theorem, that seems cool. I get that $r$ passes through the diagonal of the square and that $\theta$ also appears on the other side because of symmetry. But I still don't stee how that helps :(, thanks for the tip with the letters

Comment: By the inscribed angle theorem, you can express $\gamma $ with $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes I understood that but I already calculated $\gamma$ with $\cos$

Comment: @Flo11235 for a given square, there are infinitely many circles who satisfie that property. So, the best answer you can get is $\gamma$ as a function of $\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\angle ACG=\angle AGC=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\pi-\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)$.

Therefore $\angle CGE=\pi-\angle AGC=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\alpha}{4}$.

$\angle GEC=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ since the diagonal of a square bisects the angle.

Your angle $\theta=\angle ECG=\pi-\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\alpha}{4}\right)=\dfrac{\pi-\alpha}{4}$

[image: Square on circle]

Comment: Or: $\theta = \angle C'CE - \angle C'CG$, where $\angle C'CE = \dfrac\pi4$ and (by the inscribed angle theorem) $\angle C'CG = \dfrac12\angle GAC' = \dfrac\alpha4.$ Therefore $\theta = \dfrac\pi4 - \dfrac\alpha4.$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I also worked it out for $4$ triangles instead of $2$ and my program works! $\theta_4 = \theta_2 - (180 - 90 - {\gamma \over 2})$ if anyone is curious. $\theta_4$ stands for $4$ triagnles and $\theta_2$ for $2$ triangles which you already calculated. You could get $\theta_8$ and so on with the same way. I don't really need it but I'm just curious, how do you generalize this? I guess it would be prettier without $\gamma$.